# unable to install mpdf

Tags: php, xampp, mpdf

I have installed composer and now I'm trying to install mpdf in my project folder.
I performed the following command `composer require mpdf/mpdf`. After this I get the following error:

```
Using version ^8.0 for mpdf/mpdf
./composer.json has been created
Running composer update mpdf/mpdf
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0, ..., v8.0.3] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.4, ..., v8.0.7] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 || ~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.8, ..., v8.0.9] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.10, ..., v8.0.12] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0, ..., v8.0.12].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Hello, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf#php-versions-and-extensions) PHP 8.0 is supported since mPDF v8.0.10. Make sure you install the appropriate version.

Comment: It's right there in the error message. require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files

Answer (score 5):

I am using mpdf 8.1.2 (PHP 8.1.6, CodeIgniter 4.2.6 on Windows 11 Home Single Language) and get the same problem. It could be resolved by these 2 steps :

1. Edit php.ini file and delete the semicolon to enable gd(;extension=gd), to be (**extension=gd**).
2. Run **composer require mpdf/mpdf v8.1.2 -W** (to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions)

Comment: - Upgrading mpdf/mpdf (v6.1.3 => v8.1.2): Extracting archive
 1/2 [==============>-------------]  50%    Update of mpdf/mpdf failed
 2/2 [============================] 100%
In Filesystem.php line 314:

  Could not delete C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\api-pdf-codeigniter\api-project-pdf/vendor/composer/7087c1bf\mpdf-mpdf-a8a22f4:   
  This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed

Answer (score 2):

Install `php8.0-gd` and `php8.0-mbstring`

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd php8.0-mbstring
```

And then require the `mpdf` library with composer.

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf v8.0.10
```

Comment: this does not work as php8.0-gd is not found by apt

Comment: I uncommented the gd extension from php.ini and then used composer require mpdf/mpdf v8.2.3 for PHP 8.1
Works well